# Want to transfer data on iPhone to a program on a PC

Tags: iphone, data-transfer

I have an iPhone app that reads barcodes.  I want to transfer that data to a program I have written on my PC.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have a web server which the app transfers the barcode to and the application on the computer grabs it from. You could probably have each user make an account which they log in to on both the phone and the computer.

**EDIT:** This document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2152/_index.html describes various methods for transferring data between an iphone and a computer.

Comment: No way to transfer it "wireless"?

Comment: That is wireless, it is just dependent on both parties having an internet connection. This is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: I read the document... it appears the only way to transfer "data" is within a file, correct?  Is there no easy way to keep the wireless connection open while the iPhone app is running, then terminate the app when the connection is closed?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, haven't tried it myself: You can use the iTunes filesharing feature Apple introduced for iOS. This seems to be a good tutorial on how to use it in your App http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

The only thing is that it requires the user to import/export the files to share on their own via iTunes, if you're cool with that it sounds like a good strategy to use built-in features of iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to make it as transparent as possible.